# Estate settlement question regarding paying promissory notes

Tags: estate-planning, estate-settlement

I was the beneficiary of a life insurance policy after my loved ones death, along with 3 other family members.  Before I even received the check, the estate was asking me for money back, from each of us.

I held a promissory note payable back to the estate.  I also purchase a vehicle from the estate and owe the other beneficiaries of the estate their portion of that.  The amount I paid back to the estate upon request exceeds the amount of both the promissory note and the vehicle settlement.  Does that payment I initially made settle my legal obligation to these estate debts?

Thank you!

Comment: Ask the executor to provide a written accounting to you.

Comment: Why were they asking you for money?   What did they ask for that compelled you to pay them so quickly?    From experience, all of these financial transactions can wait longer than you think.   Stop and take a breath before you send any more checks around.  Sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses.  We were told that the estate needed to pay bills.  We are all co executors, but one of us was foremost in the process, with all of us involved in certain aspects.  We paid it back so quickly because our lawyers told us we had to, and we, not knowing any differently, did.  We trusted them to guide us as promised.  Our financial institution did not bat an eye at this either. Question ~ is this even legal?  I've been doing some digging that I should have done long ago, and am finding that it may not be.  What to do now?